# Copy a abstract model to another instance?

Tags: django

I have the following situation:

```
class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    # fields

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class A(AbstractModel):
    # no extra fields

class B(AbstractModel):
    # no extra fields
```

now i want to save one row from A to B, is there a easy way to do it? 
or do i need to copy every field on its own?

Also is there a better way in doing this? I need this, cause i have one table that could be modified by a user, but the other is frozen, from the frozen one i create pdfs, but when i change something in class A it shouldn't override something in class B, it should create a new instance of B.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> now i want to save one row from A to B, is there a easy way to do it? or do i need to copy every field on its own?

You can use the `model_to_dict` from `django.forms` to generate an initial kwargs dict:

```
from django.forms import model_to_dict
a = A.objects.get(..)
kwargs = model_to_dict(a)
kwargs.pop('id')
b = B.objects.create(**kwargs)
```

Comment: i think your answer is the same as above, and this works great! (i hope)
i would upvote you both, but i can't due to my reputation. sorry.
still +1

Answer (score 0):

You should have to copy each field in new instance of `B` and then save it.

But there is a shortcut way.

```
b_obj.__dict__ = a_obj.__dict__
#remove any foreign key/id/default fields
b_obj.__dict__.pop('id')
...
b_obj.save()
```

But its undocumented method, so has its own risks!

Comment: that's not really cool, since the model has like 20 fields and some ForeignKeys shouldn't get deleted.
I hoped that i could instance the other model or something. bad that this won't work